# Not able to read delta parquet files inside a container from storage account in azure databricks

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, delta-lake

There is spark command which writes the output dataframe in delta format inside a container omega  from python notebook

when to try to read a delta file from this omega container  using spark ,it throw the below error

```
omega_2022_06_06_path = 'dbfs:/mnt/omega/'  + 'part-00000-234567-c000.snappy.parquet'

omega_2022_06_07_path = 'dbfs:/mnt/omega/'  + 'part-00000-987898-c000.snappy.parquet'


omega_06_06_DF = spark.read.format("delta").load(omega_2022_06_06_path)
omega_06_07_DF = spark.read.format("delta").load(omega_2022_06_07_path)



 AnalysisException: A partition path fragment should be the form like `part1=foo/part2=bar`. The partition path:part-00000-234567-c000.snappy.parquet
```

I am not sure what is partition fragment here , This omega container simply has some delta files , basically there is no directory inside omega container

Can someone help me how do i resolve this issue

Comment: Why do you need to read specific files?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read only specific files, then you need to read them using the `parquet` format, not `delta`.  The `delta` format represents a table as a whole (all data files and metadata), not specific pieces. If you need to extract specific data from Delta table usually you do `spark.read.load` and then use `.filter` to limit the scope to necessary data.

Comment: I did this and it only gave me output produced on particular date val df = spark.read
  .format("delta")
  .option("timestampAsOf", "2022-06-06")
  .load("/mnt/omega/")